# html-pdf: How to ensure image doesn't span a page break

Tags: css, image, chart.js, html-pdf

I am using [html-pdf](https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-pdf) to convert HTML to PDF. To add Graphs, I am using [Chart.js](https://www.chartjs.org/).

When generate the PDF, Graph break into two pages as shown in below image.

This is how I add the Graph.

```
<canvas id="bar-chart" class="canvas-styles margin-top-20" 
 style="display: block; page-break-before: auto; page-break-after: auto; page-break-inside: avoid;">
</canvas>
```

[image]

How could I solve this?

Comment: If you surround the `canvas` with a relatively positioned `div`, and set that container to `inline-block`, does that help? Or maybe just move all the `style info in your `canvas` element to a parent `div` container.

Comment: @AndyHoffman Tried this and no Luck. `<div style="position: relative; display: inline-block;">
 <canvas id="bar-chart" class="canvas-styles margin-top-20" 
  style="display: block; page-break-before: auto; page-break-after: auto; page-break-inside: avoid;">
 </canvas>
</div>`

Comment: Is there any way you can post a live example somewhere? I'd love to examine it more closely.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add into your css an @print section for your div:

```
@media print {
     div#canvasWrap { width: 2.4cm; }
  }
```

And add a wrapping div around your canvas:

```
<div id="canvasWrap">
    <canvas id="bar-chart" class="canvas-styles"></canvas>
</div>
```

Add any styles you need to the wrapper ...

Comment: Thanks for the answer. `@media print {div#canvasWrap { width: 9.26cm; }  }` with this modification, worked as a charm.